# Auto mapper version 5 no definition for Mapper.Createmap

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper-5

I'am currently following a tutorial of ASP.NET MVC in which instructor use auto mapper version 4.x and now i have only option of version 5.

When I create a mapping profile in which i get an error `Mapper` does not contain a definition for `CreateMap`:

[image: You can see image here]

I've attached all pictures of :
My Mapping Profile.
My Global.asax.cs.
`/api/customer` is working fine.
`/api/movies` is not working.

Is there something wrong i did or missed something?
Here's the [link of my images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoJB1.jpg)

Comment: There are breaking changes to the API in V5 - see here: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/5.0-Upgrade-Guide

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CreateMap` is an instance method of the base class [`Profile`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/2b0d6935ae3abecf82e2a60d413beb01a398ade4/src/AutoMapper/Profile.cs#L141-L151)

Just call

```
public MappingProfile()
{
   CreateMap<A,B>() //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Anton, it resolved my problem. Can you please review my post again i've an error on calling my api.

Comment: the error says that you don't have mapping `CreateMap<Movie,MovieDTO>()`

Comment: Sorry i didn't notice that, fixed it thank you so much. @Anton